# TEST: relationship of minority students academic performance to CRT

Tags: hypothesis-testing, ordinal-data

Which test should I run if I am looking at the relationship of academic performance (outcome) by minority students (nominal variable) to their cultural responsive experience/perception (ordinal variable)?

My study will survey three different groups/population (schools) of students. I hope to analyze each population separately then aggregate the data.

Since the academic performance scores are leveled (1 to 5), I was uncertain if I should run an ordered logistic regression.  However, I am not assessing change in one variable to predict change in another variable.

I am most welcoming to any help!

Comment: ordinal logistic regression seems like an OK idea. Regression can be used purely descriptively, not only for prediction.